How does a battery link to the main current of a circuit?
When talking about the potential difference, there is the simplified explanation that the Anode and Cathode have a potential difference between them, meaning charges are "Pushed" from one side to another. However, recently I learnt that this is not as simple as just the electrons pushing from the battery like a rollercoaster of carts along the surface, and is instead caused by the electric fields, which provide the "Push".
I am just trying to confirm my understanding, before I go down the rabbit hole of circuitry with an incorrect idea of the underlying physics of what is going on.
From what I understand, the battery creates an electric field, the circuit is in an electrostatic state so already has surface charges with an electric field of which is perpendicular to the surface. These are then altered by the electric field to be slightly pointing along the wire, which then effects internal charges. The surface charges move, and build up to different densities on the bends to create an equilibrium.
Furthermore, there is a charge gradient around the simple circuit, which keeps the internal free electrons moving.
How accurate is my current knowledge?

Could you please edit "surface charges which are perpendicular", as this phrase doesn't make sense.

@PhilipWood Edited, I was ambiguous in meaning the electric field produced by surface charges are perpendicular.

Have you looked  up how batteries actually work?

@BobD Yes, I have, I suppose the question is not really about batteries. I was just using that as an example but let's pretend it can be any electromotive force. I am not asking how the chemical reactions take place, or how a battery creates a field.. I am asking about how the field by the battery (or electromotive force) proceeds to induce a current.

To extend upon this, I have read the paper where this is made to be the case. But in any physics course I have taken, I don't really see electrostatics being linked to circuit theory. Surely it should be since the circuits conductor e.g a Wire is in equilibrium just before the battery is connected, therefore the battery should induce the surface current, and then the inner free electrons.

Circuit theory assumes that Kirchhoff's theorems are valid, i.e. that both charge and energy are conserved. Energy conservation means that electromagnetic radiation can not be leaving the circuit. "Wires" in circuit theory are therefor not actual physical devices. They are parts of a graph that describes how charge flows between the nodes of lumped elements. You are correct that an actual physical wire does NOT behave like a wire in circuit theory. It creates and electromagnetic field and acts like an antenna. In the circuit theory approximation this is ignored.

You don't really see electrostatics being linked to circuit theory because the latter are not electrostatics. It is clearly in the electrodynamics part. Just read more and it will be taught properly.

imagine that you have special "sticky" fingers: your left hand can grab electrons and your right hand can grab positive charges. You are strong and your hands can collect and keep separate a large quantity of such charges by some means that is not described by electromagnetism solely but involves quantum mechanics, thermodynamics, chemistry, biochemistry, etc. All this stuff is lumped into a single electric circuit model of a fictitious thing that we call a battery and model it in its simplest manifestation as an ideal voltage source and series connected to a resistor.

@naturallyInconsistent Yes, but when the circuit is not connected to the battery, it is in an electrostatic state.

When the circuit is not connected to the battery, there is no current.

@naturallyInconsistent Yes, but as soon as I connect a battery, for example, does the batteries electric field distribute the surface charges, which then causes the inner charges to flow?

In that moment, you immediately leave electrostatics and enter electrodynamics. Stop seeking answers where they do not belong, and actually learn things properly.
